# Как узнать программно есть ли разрешение на хранение cookies в браузере chrome на андроид?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, cookie

Как можно программно в другом андроид приложении определить дал ли пользователь разрешение на хранение и/или чтение cookies в браузере chrome на андроид?

Comment: В Chrome можно посмотреть флаги [`chrome://flags/`](https://chromeum.ru/faq/chrome-flags-settings)

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Есть у Вас пример кода который можно прикрутить в свое приложение, что бы эти флаги получить программно?

Comment: К сожалению, нет. У меня была идея: получить данные страницы с помощью `HttpURLConnection` - но её реализовать не получилось, скорее всего, из-за неправильного `schema`